# Get Elements Between 2 Elements With Soup

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML code :

```
<div class="info">
    <div class="left-wrap"><span class="date">DATE-1</span></div>
</div>

<div class="clients-list">
        <div>
            <span class="client" >client1</span>
            <span class="client" >client2</span>
            <span class="client" >client3</span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="info">
    <div class="left-wrap"><span class="date" >DATE-2</span></div>
</div>
<div class="clients-list">
        <div>
            <span class="client" >client4</span>
            <span class="client" >client5</span>
        </div>
</div>
```

I want to get data related to each date , I did the following :

```
date = []
clients = []
for item in soup.find_all(class_='date'):
    date.append(item.get_text().strip())
for item in soup.find_all(class_='client'): 
    clients.append(item.get_text().strip())
print date
print clients
```

I end up with list of dates , containing "date1" and "date2", and list of clients containing clients1 to clients5.

My problem is that I cannot map clients with date , for example client1,client2 and client3 and related to date1, but I didn't find anyway to know how many clients will be under each date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.Use `find_next`() to find the next div tag and then find_all() span tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="info">
    <div class="left-wrap"><span class="date">DATE-1</span></div>
</div>

<div class="clients-list">
        <div>
            <span class="client" >client1</span>
            <span class="client" >client2</span>
            <span class="client" >client3</span>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="info">
    <div class="left-wrap"><span class="date" >DATE-2</span></div>
</div>
<div class="clients-list">
        <div>
            <span class="client" >client4</span>
            <span class="client" >client5</span>
        </div>
</div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
dates=soup.find_all(class_='date')
for date in dates:
  print(date.text)
  for item in date.find_next(class_='clients-list').find_all(class_='client'):
       print(item.text)
```

**Output**:

```
DATE-1
client1
client2
client3
DATE-2
client4
client5
```

Comment: Thank you so much , that what I was looking for

Comment: I have another question please, your code works perfectly, but in another situation I have multiple other class=clients-list under each date, when I run I get only the first one.
I tried findallnext but didn't work, 
Would you please help me

Comment: If you could post another question with example that would be great!!!

Comment: I posted another question here:

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58331914/get-multiple-elements-with-soup

Thank you

Comment: @dxtr : Added answer on the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import itertools as it, re
data = soup(html, 'html.parser').find_all('span', {'class':re.compile('client|date')})
r = [[i.text for i in b] for _, b in it.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x['class'][0] == 'client')]
result = {r[i][0]:r[i+1] for i in range(0, len(r), 2)}
```

Output:

```
{'DATE-1': ['client1', 'client2', 'client3'], 'DATE-2': ['client4', 'client5']}
```

Comment: Would you please rewrite the code in a more readable way, this line confused me
r = [[i.text for i in b] for _, b in it.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x['class'][0] == 'client')]